# How do I access a file's path without using ActiveX or Java

Tags: java, javascript, activex

I'm developing some client based application and one of my projects needs to access a file and than move this file to another folder over the network.

I've written an ActiveX for this problem but some of my customers said that they didn't use Internet Explorer so I've decided to move my program into Java.

Today I read a news: [Apple removes Java from all OS X Web browsers](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/10/apple-removes-java-from-all-os-x-web-browsers/), they are still supporting Java but they stopped including pre-installed versions of Java in OS X.

So I want to know that Is there any way to solve this problem with Javascript or something else? I don't want to use external plug-ins.

Comment: I don't think javascript will ever include unrestricted file access. Security issues.

Comment: Java should never have come 'pre-installed' on any OS, ever.  It is a plug-in, and should be downloaded and updated according to user requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to ask a web browser to move a file without using a plugin.

An `<input type="file">` will suffice for uploading a file to the server. The [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) will allow you to do more than just upload it, but that doesn't extend to moving it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should start to write this code in Java.